# Python stops printing after some time in anaconda prompt

Tags: python, anaconda

I have a piece of python code **trial.py** that looks something like this:

```
while time < 1 p.m.:
   variable = current_value_using_live_api
   print(variable)
   if variable > 100:
      exit()
   time.sleep(60)
```

Now I run this file from the **anaconda prompt** in my windows device.
Everything seems to work smoothly except after a while the anaconda prompt stops printing the value of the variable. I get the *"feeling"* that the script is still running in the background even though it's not printing anything in the prompt (obviously it's just a feeling I could be wrong). Can I please get some help in understanding why this is happening and how to resolve this?

Comment: try this in google collab...Also, code syntax is wrong in 1st line there should not be "p.m." it should be 13 if use DateTime module

Comment: Hi the above code is just a representation - I use datetime.datetime.now().time() <= datetime.time(14, 50, 0) in my actual code. The while loop executes fine for some time and then it stops printing the value of the variable.

Comment: have u tried to use it in google colab...are u getting an error like this "AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'sleep'"

Comment: it should work once you import time module I think

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "feeling". Can't you check exactly if your script is still running or not? If you have launched it as a background process, then task Manager should be able to tell you. If it is not a background process then you can see if the next propmt line has appeared. It looks like there would be two ways for your loop to exit normally

Comment: @FlyingTeller sure, when the loop has exited, it should show me the usual "(base) c:/path/>". In my case it neither prints the variable nor shows me "(base) c:/path/>".